# Help complete this proof of the inverse function derivative theorem

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function

Let $f$ be a differentiable injection on $[a,b]$.  Show $(f^{-1})'(x) = 1/f'(f^{-1}(x))$.

*Note: Proofs are available.  This question asks for help completing* this *proof*.

**Partial Proof:** For arbitrary $x$ in the domain of $f^{-1}$, write

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac {f^{-1}(x+h) - f^{-1}(x)}{h} &= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac {f^{-1}(x+h) - f^{-1}(x)}{f(f^{-1}(x+h)) - f(f^{-1}(x))}\\
&= \left[\lim_{h \to 0}\frac {f(f^{-1}(x+h)) - f(f^{-1}(x))}{f^{-1}(x+h) - f^{-1}(x)} \right]^{-1} \tag{1} \\
&= \left [f'(f^{-1}(x)) \right ]^{-1}. \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

Re (1): Since $a \mapsto a^{-1}, a \neq 0$ is continuous, and $\lim f(g(x)) = f(\lim g(x))$ for continuous $f$.

Re (2): I'm having trouble justifying this step.  It is clearly true that as $h \to 0$, then $f^{-1}(x+h) \to f^{-1}(x)$.  It is likewise true that we can interchange limits for invertible (or continuous) functions, both of which are satisfied here, and use this to change the variable of limitation.  I believe these two facts together justify Line (2), but am struggling to turn this into a clear and direct argument.

**Questions:**

1. How do I justify Line (2)?
2. Is there an alternate approach that is simpler and avoids the complexity here?
3. Is the rest of the proof correct?

I prefer responses that point me in the right direction and help me draw the correct conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may go without saying (I'm not sure about your needs) that $f^{-1}$ exists because $f$ is injective.

Questions:

1. Since $f^{-1}$ is continuous, sending $h\to 0$ also sends $f^{-1}(x+h)-f^{-1}(x)\to 0$. Then, you can rewrite the numerator in terms of a new $h$. Alternatively, use the derivative definition

$$f^\prime(x)=\lim_{y\to x} \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$$

2. There's a graphical approach that is very nice. Try thinking about inverses as reflecting about $y=x$.
3. You never explicitly used injectivity or differentiability. Do you need to? For (1), you could add a reason for why $a\neq 0$.

Comment: I don't see why $a \ne 0$ has to be true. Did you mean $f'(a) \ne 0$ ? You can't deduce that $f'$ is nonzero unless you already know that $f$ is a diffeomorphism i.e. $f$ is differentiable, bijective with a differentiable inverse.

Comment: Thanks! Re #3: (@VivekKaushik $a \neq 0$ refers to the free variable $a$ in Note 1 of the OP.)  As used there, $a \neq 0$ because $x \neq h$ and $f$ and hence $f^{-1}$ are injections, so $f^{-1}(x+h) - f^{-1}(x) \neq 0$. As you point out, this is where I need injectivity, and I should add this to Note 1.  Re differentiability: Doesn't Line 2 use it explicitly? Do I need to explicitly state "since $f$ is presumed differentiable"?

Comment: Re #1: I understand your recommendation is to write something like "Let $p = f^{-1}(x+h)$ and $q = f^{-1}(x)$.  Since $f^{-1}$ is continuous, as $h \to 0, p \to q$, and so we have $\lim_{p \to q} \frac {p-q}{f(f^{-1}(x+h)) - f(f^{-1}(x))}".  Am I understanding correctly? If so, I have two concerns: i. Isn't that essentially what I already do? And ii. How does that solve the problem I raise in Note 2, that I haven't really justified the change in limit variables?

Comment: @SRobertJames injectivity will complete your continuity argument (1), and I agree that you don’t need to mention differentiability. But, proof-based calculus courses sometimes want more details - it becomes subjective. For (2), I would simply add a change of variables like you say to make it clear. It sounds like that’s what you were already thinking, so that’s great. I just wasn’t sure that’s what you were saying, so I could have used the extra line.

Answer (score 0):

The theorem is false. What if $f(x)=x^3$ on $[-1,1]$ ? Certainly $f$ is differentiable and injective (in fact bijective), but its inverse is not differentiable at $0.$

The theorem should state something like this: If $f$ is continuously differentiable with $f'(x) \ne 0,$ then $f$ is locally invertible around $x$ and $(f^{-1})'(f(x))=\frac{1}{f'(x)}.$ This is a very special case of the Inverse Function Theorem.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, the claim should be amended to state "Show $(f^{-1})'(x) = 1/f'(f^{-1}(x))$ wherever $f'(f^{-1}(x) \neq 0$."  Does this omission affect the rest of the proof?

Comment: I think it is fine, but you need to mention explicitly that $x \in f([a,b]).$ Because you mentioned $f$ is only injective, not bijective.